# What is the use of condition_on_observations in BoTorch model? How is it different from model[input]?

Tags: python, machine-learning, bayesian, gaussian-process

I am leaning how to use BoTorch for the same and have to make my own GP network for my problem. I tried to experiment with the package and also looked into the library. I have two major questions:

According to my understanding after reading the comment in the library and the code, the condition_on_observation function is used to update the model for the new observation.

1. If my understanding is correct, why can't we just do GPmodel(torch.cat([old_y, new_y]), torch.cat([old_y, new_y]))?
2. Why and when is the condition_on_observations?

I tried doing a small experiment to check it. Why are the results different in CASE 1 and CASE 2?

In CASE 1:

I initially train the GP on a set of data points [0.02, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.5].
Then I obtain the posterior mean and variance at test point 0.8.
The mean is 0.9179 and the variance is 0.028.

```
init_x = torch.tensor([0.02, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.5], dtype=torch.double).unsqueeze(-1)
init_y = target_function(init_x).unsqueeze(-1)
best_init_y = init_y.max().item()

bounds = torch.tensor([[-2.], [10.]]) #bounds for 2D: torch.tensor([[0., 1.], [10.,2.]]) 

from botorch.models import SingleTaskGP
from gpytorch.mlls.exact_marginal_log_likelihood import ExactMarginalLogLikelihood

single_model = SingleTaskGP(init_x, init_y)
mll = ExactMarginalLogLikelihood(single_model.likelihood, single_model)

from botorch import fit_gpytorch_model
fit_gpytorch_model(mll)

with torch.no_grad():
    test_x = torch.tensor([[0.8]], dtype=torch.double)
    posterior = single_model.posterior(test_x)

    print(f'Mean is: {posterior.mean}')
    print(f'Var is: {posterior.variance}')
```

###########################################################################################

In CASE 2:

I initially train the GP on a set of data points [0.02, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35].
Then I obtain the posterior mean and variance at test point 0.8.
The mean is 0.9637 and the variance is 0.060.
Then I condition the GP on additional observations at points [0.4, 0.5] using model.condition_on_observations.
Then I obtain the posterior mean and variance at test point 0.8 again.
The mean is 0.9206 and the variance is 0.026.

```
init_x = torch.tensor([0.02, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35], dtype=torch.double).unsqueeze(-1)
init_y = target_function(init_x).unsqueeze(-1)
best_init_y = init_y.max().item()

bounds = torch.tensor([[-2.], [10.]]) #bounds for 2D: torch.tensor([[0., 1.], [10.,2.]]) 

from botorch.models import SingleTaskGP
from gpytorch.mlls.exact_marginal_log_likelihood import ExactMarginalLogLikelihood

single_model = SingleTaskGP(init_x, init_y)
mll = ExactMarginalLogLikelihood(single_model.likelihood, single_model)

single_model.parameters

from botorch import fit_gpytorch_model
fit_gpytorch_model(mll)

with torch.no_grad():
    test_x = torch.tensor([[0.8]], dtype=torch.double)
    posterior = single_model.posterior(test_x)
    
    print(f'Mean is: {posterior.mean}')
    print(f'Var is: {posterior.variance}\n')
    

extra_x = torch.tensor([0.4, 0.5], dtype=torch.double).unsqueeze(-1)
extra_y = target_function(extra_x).unsqueeze(-1)

model_conditioned = single_model.condition_on_observations(extra_x, extra_y)

with torch.no_grad():
    posterior = model_conditioned.posterior(test_x)
    
    print(f'Mean for conditioned_model is: {posterior.mean}')
    print(f'Var for conditioned_model is: {posterior.variance}\n')
    
    
mll_conditioned = ExactMarginalLogLikelihood(model_conditioned.likelihood, model_conditioned)
fit_gpytorch_model(mll_conditioned)

with torch.no_grad():
    posterior = model_conditioned.posterior(test_x)
    
    print(f'Mean for conditioned_model is: {posterior.mean}')
    print(f'Var for conditioned_model is: {posterior.variance}\n')
```

I tried doing a small experiment to check it. Why are the results different in CASE 1 and CASE 2?